# How to know $(\mathbb Z /n\mathbb Z)^*$ is cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How can I show that $(\mathbb Z /n\mathbb Z)^*$ is cyclic or not for a given $n$?

If $n$ is small like 10 or 11 then we can compute the number of elements and then can find an element whose order is $\phi(n)$. But if $n$ is large enough then how can I say it is cyclic or not?

Here $(\mathbb Z /n\mathbb Z)^*$ denotes the set of all units in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.

Need some help please..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n

Comment: Then according to wiki $(\mathbb Z/ 8\mathbb Z)^*$ is isomorphic to $C_2 \times C_2$ and the later is non-cyclic . But in $(\mathbb Z/ 8\mathbb Z)^*$ there is an element 5 (mod 8) $s.t.$ $5^4=1(mod 8)$ and this implies that $(\mathbb Z/ 8\mathbb Z)^*$ is cyclic. Am I wrong somewhere? Please check @TsemoAristide

Comment: Yes I see it now @SahibaArora. Should I delete this post?

Comment: The order of $5$ in the group is not $4$, since $5^2=1$

Comment: ooh yeah..I got it @leibnewtz